# Magento - Increase the decimal places from 2 to 4 for downloadable products

Tags: magento, download, decimal, product

I'm not able to increase the decimal places from 2 to 4 at the price-field in Magento Backend for downloadable products. Where do I have to start to find that piece of code?. Any help very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, which field do you mean to change?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant the price-field at the downloadable options. It is saving 4 places after the comma, but it does only display 2 - a bit confusing for the administrator in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your mystery lies in

Mage_Downloadable_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links

```
    /**
    * Return formated price with two digits after decimal point
    *
    * @param decimal $value
    * @return decimal
    */
    public function getPriceValue($value)
    {
        return number_format($value, 2, null, '');
    }
```

HTH :)